# Non standard recurrence

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I start from the following vectorial function

```
r[n_, x_, a_] := Block[{y = x},
  ja = Table[
    If[y[[i]] <= (\[LeftFloor]y[[i]]\[RightFloor] + \[LeftCeiling]y[[
         i]]\[RightCeiling])/
      2, \[LeftFloor]y[[i]]\[RightFloor], \[LeftCeiling]y[[
       i]]\[RightCeiling]], {i, Length[y]}];
  ta = Total[ja];
  tb = Which[ta == 14, ja, ta < 19, {1.588, 5.9338, 13.4779}/(
    a (0.95)^n), ta > 19, N[{1.588, 5.9338, 13.4779}/(a (1.05)^n)]]
```

Now I would like to iterate this function many time. By hand this gives

```
zz = {1.588, 5.9338, 13.4779}
r[0, zz, 1]
r[1, r[0, zz, 1], 1]
r[2, r[1, zz, 1], 1]
r[3, r[1, r[2, r[1, zz, 1], 1], 1], 1]
```

Quickly, this way becomes unreadable. I have tried to use `@*` and the other possibilité Like `FixedPoint` and other command but I failed. Could some one help me to established correctly the recurrence.

Comment: `FoldList[r[#2, #1, 1] &, zz, Range[m]]`, which would iterate your function `m` times. Do you need it to iterate to a fixed point? Is it guaranteed to reach a fixed point for any input?

Comment: Super  Thanks for our complex systems it converges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you could go here. But the simplest is probably

```
i = 1;
FixedPoint[r[i++, #, 1] &, zz]

(* Out= {1, 4, 9} *)
```

(Start at `i = 1` because `r[0, zz, 1] == zz`).

`Fold[r[#2, #1, 1] &, zz, Range[m]]` is not ideal because you need to be sure to take `m` large enough, but you don't want it to be churning through unnecessary computations. You could get around this by exiting `Fold` with `Throw` when an equilibrium is reached, and `Catch` the result (as in the `Fold` documentation). But in my tests that seemed remarkably slow, so I'm going to ignore it.

A straightforward `While` loop could be the answer if you find your iterative loop getting more complicated (say, that `a` parameter starts varying). But for what you're needing now, `While` is looking unnecessarily complicated next to `FixedPoint`.