# A nice way to fold a non constant recursive function

Tags: programming

The following code works exactly as expected. It constructs the Balinski-Young apportionment method. It is composed of two parts
1) the construction of the Balyski-Young function

```
v = {1000, 2000, 1400, 3000};(* votes par partis*)
s = 20;(* nb de sièges *)
as = Table[0, {i, Length[v]}](* allocation intermediaire initiale *)
qbpy[n_, v_, as_] := 
 Block[{x = v, y = as, h = n}, r = Range[Length[x]];
  qq = N[v/Total[v] h];
  t = Table[{r[[i]], 
     If[(y + 1)[[i]] > ⌈qq⌉[[i]], -1, 
      N[v[[i]]/(y[[i]] + 1)]]}, {i, Length[y]}];
  pt = Sort[t, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &];
  ttt = Table[
    If[i == pt[[1, 1]], y[[i]] = y[[i]] + 1, y[[i]]], {i, 
     Length[as]}]]
```

2) Then it iterates like this :

```
qbpy[1, v, as]
qbpy[2, v, qbpy[1, v, as]]
qbpy[3, v, qbpy[2, v, qbpy[1, v, as]]]
qbpy[4, v, qbpy[3, v, qbpy[2, v, qbpy[1, v, as]]]]
qbpy[5, v, qbpy[4, v, qbpy[3, v, qbpy[2, v, qbpy[1, v, as]]]]]
```

to the restriction that the iteration must go to `s=26`

Now I have to questions :

A) Is there a Mathematica way to automitize the iterations. I have tried with `FoldList`, `FixedPoint`... I can write a recurrence but I search Ifthere is a simpler way.

B) Is there a way to wrap all this stuff in a `balyouapp[v_,s_]` function --- i.e: to write a `Module` including a `Block`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Rest@FoldList[qbpy[#2, v, #] &, as, Range[5]] // Column
```

[image]

A wild guess re part (B)

```
balyouapp[v_, s_] := Fold[qbpy[#2, v, #] &, ConstantArray[0, Length[v]], Range[s]]

balyouapp[{1000, 2000, 1400, 3000}, 26]
```

> {3, 7, 5, 11}

An alternative version for `qbpy`:

```
qbpy2[n_, v_, as_] := Module[{pt}, 
 pt = SortBy[Table[{i, If[(as + 1)[[i]] > ⌈N[v/Total[v] n]⌉[[i]], -1, 
     N[v[[i]]/(as[[i]] + 1)]]}, {i, Length[as]}], -#[[2]] &];
 as + Table[Boole[i == pt[[1, 1]]], {i, Length[as]}]]
```

Used in place of `qbpy` it gives the same result:

```
Fold[qbpy2[#2, v, #] &, ConstantArray[0, Length[v]], Range[26]]
```

> {3, 7, 5, 11}

Comment: Thanks for A) and for B) what can I do

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki, not sure i understand part (B). Please check if my hunch is correct.

Comment: With the second definition, I have the correct result but before it gives me a strange lot of information . In fact I would like to run  Fold or FoldList directly in the same process than qbpy

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @kglr's fine answer, for the sake of completeness, you can also use `NestList`:

```
i=1;
Rest@NestList[qbpy[i++, v, #] &, as, 5] // TableForm
```

[image]

and (through a slight modification of [your previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148937/non-standard-recurrence/148942#148942)), `FixedPoint`:

```
i = 1;
FixedPoint[qbpy[i++, v, #] &, as, 100]

(* {13, 27, 19, 41} *)
```

(That's the result of 100 iterations because I'm not sure it'll converge. If you're sure it will, then you can get rid of the last argument.)